# SIGINT not captureble, in python

Tags: python, interrupt, bottle

I am trying to catch cntrl-c events so that I can gracefully shutdown my server( using the bottle framework). However, when I test this, I never hit the stop method in the debugger and I get a unclosed socket warning as well to confirm this. What am I missing here.

```
class CFMServer(ServerAdapter):

    def run(self, handler):
        from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server, WSGIRequestHandler
        self.server = make_server(self.host, self.port, handler, **self.options)
        # set signal handlers
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.stop)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.stop)
        try:
            self.server.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.stop()
            raise

    def stop(self):
        pdb.set_trace()
        manager.save()
        self.server.server_close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('port', metavar='P', type=int,
                        help='Port to assign the server in localhost')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    port = args.port
    server = CFMServer(host='localhost', port=port)
    service.run(server=server, debug=True)
```

Here is my output from the shell, when I interrupt.

```
    Bottle v0.13-dev server starting up (using CFMServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:11245/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cfm-service", line 127, in <module>
    service.run(server=server, debug=True)
  File "/repo/ekrmann/next-debugger/python/emca/gdbcmds/emca/core/third_party/bottle.py", line 881, in run
    run(self, **kwargs)
  File "/repo/ekrmann/next-debugger/python/emca/gdbcmds/emca/core/third_party/bottle.py", line 3476, in run
    server.run(app)
  File "./cfm-service", line 108, in run
    self.server.serve_forever()
  File "/app/vbuild/RHEL6-i686/python/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 237, in serve_forever
    ready = selector.select(poll_interval)
  File "/app/vbuild/RHEL6-i686/python/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/selectors.py", line 367, in select
    fd_event_list = self._poll.poll(timeout)
TypeError: stop() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 11245)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `stop` method does not implement the Python signal handler signature. Instead of

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.stop)
```

write a helper function that does:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda _signum, _stack: self.stop())
```